# Is there an Attribute to tell Entity Framework not to update a field?

Tags: entity-framework-6, code-first

I have a view of a table that includes one field from another table.

When I change data, and then tell EF to save, it gives me an error saying that multiple tables are affected and thus can't be updated.

Is there an attribute that I can put on the one field to tell EF not to update it?

The extra field will never need to be updated.

If not, is there some other way to resolve this?

Comment: I think I found it: `ReadOnly(true)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct attribute to use is `[ReadOnly]`

Answer (score 0):

The full stacktrace and some information about the unterlying database could help.
Maybet the problem is db specific. For instance MySQL can only update views with view type `Merge` and not `TempTable`.

And you should at least say what strategy (code first / database first / model first) you are using.

As you asked for an attribute: there is the `StoreGenerationPattern` enumeration.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.data.metadata.edm.storegeneratedpattern(v=vs.110).aspx

Try setting it to `None` for this column.